# How to insert exactly same dataFrame in multiple target including root datasource using Spark function?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to read data from a single source, then write it back to same source then write to another source.

Source can be different: HDFS, Mongo, Kafka ...

With local testing, I have a weird behaviour.

This is my first test: I persist the data on disk to not recompute the data from original source:

```java
Dataset<Row> rootDataframe = sparkSession
        .read()
        .option("header", true)
        .csv("folder1");

Dataset<Row> cachedDataFrame = rootDataframe.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());

cachedDataFrame
        .write()
        .option("header", true)
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .csv("folder1");

cachedDataFrame
        .write()
        .option("header", true)
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .csv("folder2");

cachedDataFrame.unpersist();
```

This doesn't work as I intended, because of persist function. The cached data is invalidated by my first write that writes it back to original source. In my folder2, I get duplicated data (the original one and the one written by my first operation). This JIRA ticket looks like my problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24596.

But if I don't use persist, this work as I want, my second write operation isn't affected by my first one. I think this is because the cache isn't invalidated and metadata stay unchanged.

If you take a look at physical plan, I think that `InMemoryFileIndex` isn't recalculated even if I clean cache manually.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan csv [COUNTRY#10,CITY#11] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/D:/dev/Intellij-project/folder1, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<COUNTRY:string,CITY:string>
```

```java
Dataset<Row> rootDataframe = sparkSession
        .read()
        .option("header", true)
        .csv("folder1");

Dataset<Row> cachedDataFrame = rootDataframe
cachedDataFrame.explain(true);

cachedDataFrame
        .write()
        .option("header", true)
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .csv("folder1");

sparkSession.sharedState().cacheManager().clearCache();

cachedDataFrame
        .write()
        .option("header", true)
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .csv("folder2");
```

But this behaviour is different with other data sources, for example with MongoDB, if I don't persist the data, the data is, as intended duplicated, because the second write operation will read the data from the first write.

Is there a way to insert the same data in multiple data sources, potentially including root data source in different target using only Spark?

This seems to be impossible using dataframe persisting. Maybe with dataframe checkpointing?  Or should I use external data storage as an intermediate data store? Dirty coding to break the lineage? Of course, I can't reverse write order, this is a simplified example, I can have multiple source that write to same multiple target.

Spark: 2.4.4 
Java 8

Comment: any reason you're using 2.4.4 when the current latest is 3.3.1? could be due to any number of bugs that have been fixed.

Comment: I using CDP version 7.1.X

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't find it [in docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.persist), but AFAIK `persist()` is a lazy operation, so just like `where` or `select` etc it won't execute/do anything, it just adds onto the execution plan. It'll execute only when you trigger some action like `count` or `write`.

Assuming you have a valid usecase for duplicating data in `folder1` (as baffling as it is) by reading from it and writing back to it. I would have more more confidence in following options:

1. Change the order. Write back to `folder1` last.

```py
df = spark.read.csv('folder1')
# changed order folder2 then 1
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv('folder2')
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).csv('folder1')
```

2. Make a copy of `folder1` (instead of `persist()`) and use that as source for all subsequent reads.

```py
shutils.copy('folder1', 'folder1_copy')
# OR spark.read.csv('folder1').write.csv('folder1_copy')
df = spark.read.csv('folder1_copy')
# original order folder1 then 2
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).csv('folder1')
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv('folder2')
```

Comment: 1) As i said i can't change the order. This is over simplified example to present the problem.

Comment: @maximeG hope #2 works for you then..